# String replacement not working

Tags: python

I'm a bit embarrassed to ask:

but why won't this successfully work? the .statswith method is fine here, returning True, but i can't get this replace to work...

```
sandwich = "Au Cheval Cheeseburger"
restaurant = "Au Cheval"
if sandwich.startswith(restaurant):
    sandwich.replace(restaurant, "")
print sandwich
```

(if you can't tell, i want sandwich to just read Cheeseburger. Is there also a more efficient way to do this than going thru string replace?

thanks everyone.

EDIT: God i knew it was something silly. It's late and the brain's fried. thanks everyone.

Comment: u'l have to reassign the replace string to 'sandwich' variable in order to hold the value

Answer (score 6):

From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

> The method replace() returns a copy of the string in which the occurrences of old have been replaced with new

Try `sandwich = sandwich.replace(restaurant, "")`

Answer (score 3):

string replacement returns a copy.

```
sandwich = sandwich.replace(restaurant, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You were doing fine but till the replace method

> The replace methods just replaces and provides the string it does not
>   store it in the variable

Since you did not not store it the variable is not changed

```
sandwich = "Au Cheval Cheeseburger"
restaurant = "Au Cheval"
if sandwich.startswith(restaurant):
    sandwich=sandwich.replace(restaurant, "")
print sandwich
```

previously you did not save it

> sandwich.replace(restaurant, "")

But to save the replacement changes you have to save it

> sandwich=sandwich.replace(restaurant, "")

Answer (score 0):

```html
sandwich = "Au Cheval Cheeseburger"
restaurant = "Au Cheval"
if sandwich.startswith(restaurant):
    sandwich = sandwich.replace(restaurant, "")
print sandwich
```